# Moved Angular project. Reinstall all dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an Angular project, worked fine on laptop A. Today i copied thw whole folder on another laptop. Installed nodejs, and ran "npm install".
But the "ng serve" command still won't work because ng is not recognizable command.
The @angular folders ar present in node_modules.
What is missin? Path settings in windows? Or i need to reinstall angular manually?
Thank you.

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running *ng serve* assumes *ng* is installed globally. Since you just moved the project to a different machine, where I assume you don't have *@angular/cli* installed, just run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

or

```
yarn global add @angular/cli
```